# ReactiveX onComplete triggered before the last onNotify

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Consider the following pipeline:

1. Buffer items into packs
2. Observe these packs in a threadpool thread
3. Do some asynchronous processing over these packs

If the process has finished, setting the source observable to *complete* will cause the buffer to emit the current pack as-is. However the processing part will get the complete event before it gets the last pack.

My idea was to wait on this last pack to be processed but since I get the *OnComplete* before the *OnNext* I can't seem to do it through ReactiveX mechanisms.

Is there any way I can get the OnComplete to happen *after* the last OnNext?

Here's a sample for simulating this behavior ([available as a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZbCoS0)):

```
    var publications = 
        obs
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("to buffer {0}", x), () => Console.WriteLine("to buffer complete"))
        .Buffer(2)
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("from buffer {0}", ShowContent(x)), () => Console.WriteLine("from buffer complete"))
        .ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("to selectmany {0}", ShowContent(x)), () => Console.WriteLine("to selectmany complete"))
        .SelectMany(x => Test(x).ToEnumerable())
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("notify {0}", x), () => Console.WriteLine("complete"));

    publications
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("publications notify {0}", x), () => Console.WriteLine("publications complete"))
        .Subscribe()
        ;

    obs.OnNext(1);
    obs.OnNext(2);
    obs.OnNext(3);

    var nextpub = publications.FirstAsync();

    obs.OnCompleted();

    nextpub.Wait();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a bit of a mess to decode... I think you are just subscribing to the `publications` observable twice:

- Once where you explicitly call `Subscribe()`
- Once where you are implicitly calling it via `FirstAsync()`

If you rearrange a little as follows. Replace the lines where you subscribe to publications the first time with:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Unit>();

var nextpub = publications
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("publications notify {0}", x),
        () => Console.WriteLine("publications complete"))
    .Subscribe(_ => {}, () => tcs.SetResult(Unit.Default));
```

Remove the line with `FirstAsync()` and replace the call to `nextpub.Wait()` with:

```
tcs.Task.Wait();
```

This is NOT a recommended way to write Rx code - just the quickest hack to fix the code you have. You should typically process your results in a subscriber, and not block for completion. e.g:

```
SomeObservable.Subscribe(x => /* handle result */);
```

Comment: I understand that blocking isn't a *reactive* thing to do, but the real situation I was dealing with was flushing a pipeline and wait for its completion before terminating a process. I guess I was going too far in trying to do everything with Rx methods.

Answer (score 2):

In Rx it is important to understand that there is a contract of behaviour for an observable. You will **always** get this sequence from the built-in operators:

> OnNext*(OnCompleted|OnError)?

So, zero or more (possibly infinite) "OnNext" calls followed, optionally, by either an "OnCompleted" or an "OnError" call.

You will **not ever** get "OnCompleted" before an "OnNext" - for a single observable.

Now, your code **seems** to be behaving differently - but it is not.

You actually have two independent subscriptions to your source observable.

Here is how one subscription looks like:

```
    var publications = 
        obs
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("to buffer {0}", x), () => Console.WriteLine("to buffer complete"))
        .Buffer(2)
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("from buffer {0}", ShowContent(x)), () => Console.WriteLine("from buffer complete"))
        .ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("to selectmany {0}", ShowContent(x)), () => Console.WriteLine("to selectmany complete"))
        .SelectMany(x => Test(x).ToEnumerable())
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("notify {0}", x), () => Console.WriteLine("complete"));

    publications
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("publications notify {0}", x), () => Console.WriteLine("publications complete"))
        .Subscribe(); /* Subscription #1 here! */

    obs.OnNext(1);
    obs.OnNext(2);
    obs.OnNext(3);

    obs.OnCompleted();
```

And here is the other:

```
    var publications = 
        obs
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("to buffer {0}", x), () => Console.WriteLine("to buffer complete"))
        .Buffer(2)
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("from buffer {0}", ShowContent(x)), () => Console.WriteLine("from buffer complete"))
        .ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("to selectmany {0}", ShowContent(x)), () => Console.WriteLine("to selectmany complete"))
        .SelectMany(x => Test(x).ToEnumerable())
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("notify {0}", x), () => Console.WriteLine("complete"));

    var nextpub = publications.FirstAsync();

    obs.OnCompleted();

    nextpub.Wait(); /* Subscription #2 here! */
```

If we only look at "Subscription #1" and we change the scheduler to `Scheduler.Immediate` we get the follow order of execution:

```
to buffer 1
to buffer 2
from buffer [1, 2]
to selectmany [1, 2]
> thread: 28
notify ()
publications notify ()
to buffer 3
to buffer complete
from buffer [3]
to selectmany [3]
> thread: 28
notify ()
publications notify ()
from buffer complete
to selectmany complete
complete
publications complete
```

This still looks like we get `to buffer complete` before values come out. But this is misleading. The `.Do(...)` operator is specifically introduced to allow side-effects to be introduced into the Rx pipeline. So it may make it appear that things are happening out of order, but if you take each step in the Rx pipeline that you've created you'll see that each step follows the "OnNext*(OnCompleted|OnError)" contract perfectly.

You really need to focus on a single step in the pipeline and you'll find it all happens correctly.

Comment: OnNext*(OnCompleted|OnError) or OnNext*(OnCompleted|OnError)? (question mark included) - i.e. termination is optional.

Comment: @JamesWorld - Yes, you're right. I tried expressing that there might be an infinite number of "OnNext" which implies an optional termination, but I like yours better.